# how to stop the flow of code after return json in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am sending a response on if something is not found like user is not found but the code still executes after sending the json. this json is written in another class. from where it returns.

```
var user = new UserClass(obj, null);
var userObj = user.getUser(res, req, 'user');

        function UserClass(obj, result) {
            this.obj = obj;
            this.result = result;
        }


    UserClass.prototype.getUser = function (res, req, state) {
      return res.format({
           json: function () {
            res.send({
            status: 404,
            message: "Not Found"
                });
            }
         });
    }
```

How can I stop the flow of code execution after this return statement.

Comment: why are you using res.send inside res.format? Is it necessary?

Comment: @QoP, just for a convention it is not necessary

Comment: @QoP. I have also updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to send a json as a response

```
return res.status(401).json({message: "Not Found});
```

You have to use the status(401) if you want it to be an error, otherwise it will return 200.

Comment: it is still executing the next flow of code from where the class is called

Comment: Well I can't see that class, can you provide it?

Comment: I have got it what's the issue it returns the server reponse in the object

Comment: you are managing your http request in a really really weird way.

Comment: What I can do is to return json error after user not found return means not doing any http request in a class. rather do the http request from that route where the class is called

Comment: what are you using to handle your routes? express?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109925/discussion-between-java-newbie-and-qop).